# Rails: Error in retrieving nested data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to model a system where a student works in a box which is associated with a practice.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to   :box

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to   :practice
   has_many     :students

class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many     :boxes
```

I was able to save some test data and want to make the index page more readable by showing the box number and its practice description but I don't get it right.

```
<td><%= student.box.number %> in Practice <% student.box.practice.description %></td>
```

I get an undefined method for "description" although I can see in the server logs that the "correct" SQL search is done. Probably a mistake of beginners but I don't know where to look.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should avoid long method chains like this. Also, can you post the full backtrace. Is it possible that `student.box.practice` is nil?

Comment: Thank you. How can I avoid long method chains? I'm just starting with rails so my knowledge is quite little. Can you point me to some tutorials where I can learn how to make it better? Backtrace will follow.

Comment: Shame on me: Yes, you were right. It was nil. Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Avoiding long message chains is referred to as the "law of Demeter"; it's debated how important it is when you're just accessing attributes as opposed to modifying attributes, but it's still good for readability. If you find that you are accessing an attribute often like student.box.practice.description, you can delegate description to Box (in the Student model), and in turn delegate it to Practice (in the Box model). Then you can just call student.description

Comment: Thanks Fred for explaining this. I'll work on the readability of my code.