# Rails: How to test delegated methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

After I've [reworked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703779/rails-error-in-retrieving-nested-data) my rails app I ran in some errors in my tests which I can not figure out. I thought that through "delegate" Rails magically knows even in testing which test data is to use, to test and that I don't have to declare those delegated data in the fixtures again (since I haven't found anything about it). Since I'm using the scaffolded tests I assumed that they should at least work seamlessly - probably a nooby idea...

Maybe you have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Here the models:

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :practice
  delegate :prac_name, to: :practice

  has_many :students

  validates :practice_id, presence: true
  validates :box_name,    presence: true, length: { in: 2..20 }
end

class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :boxes

  validates :prac_name, presence: true, length: { in: 5..50 }
end
```

The controller:

```
# GET /boxes
def index
  @boxes = Box.all.order(box_name: :asc)
end
```

The view:

```
<tbody>
  <% @boxes.each do |box| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= box.box_name %></td>
      <td><%= box.prac_name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', box %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_box_path(box) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', box, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The fixtures:

```
# box
one:
  box_name: MyString
  practice_id: 1

two:
  box_name: MyString
  practice_id: 1

# practice
one:
  prac_name: MyString

two:
  prac_name: MyString
```

And here the test:

```
test 'should get index' do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:boxes)
end
```

The result is that I get this error message from guard/minitest for "get index" and "show box". Why is practice nil? (ActionView::Template::Error: Box#prac_name delegated to practice.prac_name, but practice is nil) Isn't it declared through the practice fixture? Apparently not but why?

```
ERROR["test_should_get_index", BoxesControllerTest, 3.196711939992383]
 test_should_get_index#BoxesControllerTest (3.20s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Box#prac_name delegated to practice.prac_name, but practice is nil: #<Box id: 298486374, box_name: "MyString", created_at: "2016-04-27 07:54:37", updated_at: "2016-04-27 07:54:37", practice_id: 1>
            app/models/box.rb:3:in `rescue in prac_name'
            app/models/box.rb:3:in `prac_name'
            app/views/boxes/index.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_boxes_index_html_erb__3226877961716035159_70232972217220'
            activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
            activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
            app/views/boxes/index.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_boxes_index_html_erb__3226877961716035159_70232972217220'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
            /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
            activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
            activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
            activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
            actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:639:in `process'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:67:in `process'
            actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:514:in `get'
            test/controllers/boxes_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:BoxesControllerTest>'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:108:in `block (3 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:205:in `capture_exceptions'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:105:in `block (2 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:256:in `time_it'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:104:in `block in run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:331:in `on_signal'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:276:in `with_info_handler'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:103:in `run'
            minitest-reporters (1.1.8) lib/minitest/reporters.rb:48:in `run_with_hooks'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:778:in `run_one_method'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:305:in `run_one_method'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:293:in `block (2 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:292:in `each'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:292:in `block in run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:331:in `on_signal'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:318:in `with_info_handler'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:291:in `run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:152:in `block in __run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:152:in `map'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:152:in `__run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:129:in `run'
            minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
            /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
            /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
            -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Thanks!

Comment: 2 questions: 1. is that the same yml in fixtures? 2. Are you sure that practice with id 1 is present? NOTE: fixtures isn't quite useful practice, try factory_girl instead to create instances of models

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your fast response! @1: yes that's the content of boxes.yml and practices.yml. @2: I thought that the fixtures are the data that is filled in the test.db during the tests. In that logic I thought that by declaring "practice one" practice can't be nil. Or which is the testing data? In my seeds.rb practice is filled also.

Comment: so what are the answers?

Comment: Sorry, hitting Return to get a new line is "too confusing"...

Comment: have you use **seeds.db** in test env? it is mostly for developpemt, try use factory_girl, Also you can set breakpoint to the code before exception with `pry` gem. to make sure if practice.id=1 is present

Comment: I probably have not seeds.db in the test env. How would I do that? And I'll have a look at factory_girl. Thank you! Update: I've found the way to use seeds.rb in test. So I'll try factory_girl also.

Comment: seeds.db isnt requited in test, since al the instances it generated by factory girl

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about the comments I've looked at the test.sqlite again and have found my mistake within the fixtures: Instead of explicitly declaring an id of another table I've changed it to the name of the other table and referencing to it like this:

```
one:
  box_name: MyString
  practice: one

two:
  box_name: MyString
  practice: two
```

Now my tests pass. So it wasn't a problem with "delegate" as I've first assumed.
And I will have a look at factory_girl, nevertheless.

```
#wrong
practice_id: 1

#right
practice: one
```